# Lin2Sql No supported translation to sql exception

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the following code.

```
    var query =
           (
             from i in _service.GetTimesheetWeeklys()
             from s in _service.GetStatuses()
             where i.ProjectID == _projectid &&
                   s.ID == i.Status
             select new
             {
                 InvoiceID = i.ID,
                 DocumentTotal = i.WeekTotal.ToString(),
                 Created = i.Created,
                 WeekEnding = i.WeekEnding,
                 Status = s.staStatus
             }
           ).Skip(_pageIndex * _pageSize).Take(_pageSize);
```

I am getting a "No suported translation exception".

I am not that experienced with Linq2Sql
and got that lin2sql code from a previous post.

Any ideas why this would be??

I am guessing it is the join syntax.

Malcolm

Comment: Looking at that I think we'd need to know what the two methods on _service are doing - that's not obviously Linq to SQL (Linq yes, but "to sql" is hidden) so the issue is a bit more complicated than can be seen from that code snipet. In terms of progress towards an answer, queries aren't actually resolved 'til needed so if the two method calls from service are return Linq to SQL queries then it will be the compound query that is having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

At least a Problem lies in here `i.WeekTotal.ToString()` .

Calling `ToString()` is not supported and L2S couldn't translate it into sql.